# XML, xslt filter text

Tags: xml, xslt

I have xml

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
>    <offer> 
>       <products> 
>          <product id="1"> 
>             <description> 
>                <long_desc>
>                   <![CDATA[<div id="projector-longdescription-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
>                   <div id="projector-longdescription-table">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>]]>
>                </long_desc>
>             </description> 
>          </product> 
>       </products>
>    </offer>
> ```

and I want to get it

> ```
>    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
>    <offer> 
>       <products> 
>          <product id="1"><div id="projector-longdescription-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
>          </product> 
>       </products>
>    </offer>
> ```

So I want to filter element "long desc" only div projector-longdescription-description.

Comment: Please describe, how do you get that textstring "Donec libero magna, posuere a libero  vel, hendrerit vulputate quam." Is it the 5. sentence? Is it a hard-coded string you get outside of xslt?

Comment: @michael.hor257k
Not identical, first div: projector-longdescription-DESCRIPTION, second div: projector-longdescription-TABLE. Lorem ipsum is an example.

Comment: Still not clear what you know that would help select the correct substring.

Comment: Note that CDATA can be parsed as XML only if your processor supports XSLT 3.0 (or has an extension function to do so). Otherwise this is an exercise in string manipulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CDATA contains arbitrary character data so it is not parsed => no xpath to elements inside of it.

You "can" try it with string manipulations like `substring-before` and so.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a `<xsl:value-of select="comment()" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>` as shown in http://xmlplease.com/charactermap

You will get both the divs.

If you want to keep only one `div`, the best is then to reparse the output in another XSL. Using `substring-before` will probably be unsafe (what if `Lorem ipsum` contains a `<div/>`?)